# How to insert empty_clob() from java to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I am having an NCLOB column in oracle. When I create a row, I need to insert an empty_clob() using normal java insert query. 
Does anyone know how this is done? I am looking for something like the one below from java.

`INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(1,'Abraham','empty_clob')`;

Thanks and Regards,
Abraham Menacherry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should correct your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES(1,'Abraham',empty_clob());
```

You should also take a look [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions047.htm).

The empty_clob function is also useful as default value for the clob column.